# Objective C: -1 < 0 return false

Tags: objective-c, conditional-statements

Is there any difference between this 2?

```
int count = 0;
for (UIView *view in scrollView.subviews) {
    NSLog(@"%d < %d", [json[@"images"] count] - 1, count);
    // Output: -1 < 0
    if ([json[@"images"] count] - 1 < count) break;
}
```

and

```
int count = 0, maxIndex = [json[@"images"] count] - 1;
for (UIView *view in scrollView.subviews) {
    NSLog(@"%d < %d", maxIndex, count);
    // Output: -1 < 0
    if (maxIndex < count) break;
}
```

What I've facing just now was, the **first** solution didn't `break` the loop, whereas the **second** solution did.

Is there any reason behind?

Comment: Maybe the JSON indexer returns a string rather than an integer?

Comment: Is not `json[@"images"]` but is the `count` property, should be integer. I put `%d` there, no warning, that means is definitely integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats because `count` is `NSUInteger` property. Therefore it will never be `-1` in your case.And in your second case you're assigning `maxIndex` to `int`, which then gives you `-1`.

So try this to clearly understand whats happening.

```
int count = 0;
NSUInteger maxIndex = [json[@"images"] count] - 1;
for (UIView *view in scrollView.subviews) {
NSLog(@"%d < %d", maxIndex, count);
// Output: -1 < 0
if (maxIndex < count) break;  //This will not break either as maxIndex will never be `-1`
```

}

Also,in your `NSLog` your using `%d` which is format specifier for type `int` , try `%lu or %lx`

Hope this helps

Comment: The comment about using `NSLog()` with `%lu` and `%lx` is not quite right as `NSUInteger` changes size on 32- and 64-bit builds.  If you want to support both you will need to use that format specifier **and** cast the value to `long`.